Minimize the number of pieces in the cube that you build
Consider the following slanted pyramid which is made from 30 unit cubes:

Step 1:  Delete any 3 unit cubes.  There is no restriction on which unit cubes are deleted.  These 3 deleted unit cubes are no longer part of the puzzle.
Step 2:  Dissect the reduced pyramid into pieces and rearrange the pieces to form a 3x3x3 cube.
This constructed cube will be made up of a number of pieces.  The goal is to minimize the number of pieces in the cube.

You only need

 two pieces!

Here's how:

 Firstly, remove the three pieces marked with Xs in the image below.
 Then, separate it into two pieces: the ones marked with the line in the image below, and everything else remaining.
 That piece can then be placed on top of the green blocks to create a full 3x3x3 cube. (You'll have to visualise this one, I don't have an image for it.) This is obviously optimal as the puzzle cannot be done with only one piece, as a 3x3x3 subset of the original diagram does not exist.


So elegant! Color those 5 pieces blue.
